# Ui gets shrink when softkeyboard opens in mobile browser

Tags: reactjs, soft-keyboard

Ui gets shrink when softkeyboard opens in mobile browser in react js, does any one this issue before

Answer (score 0):

> Hi guys I got the workaround for this ,down here it check for the any resize movement in ui if found then changes the swipe (state) value which is boolean ,by using this boolean value I changed the class conditionally to perrent div and gave 100% with which made my UI stable

```
componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.resize.bind(this));
    this.resize();
   }

   resize() {
    this.setState({ swipe: window.innerWidth <= 760 });
   }
```